# fails Silent installation of exe

Tags: cmd

We are unable to install silently a exe with command `Setup.exe /SP- /VERYSILENT`.

It shows the message please enter the name and goes to exit. I don't know how it is happened. Whether it requires any parameter or not. But please help me to do this.

Comment: This doesn't quite seem like a programming question at this point, however... what do you get if you run `setup.exe /?`?

Comment: @notjustme I tried it but it started installation like normal

Comment: I suggest you turn to the developer and ask them what the command line parameters are and how to use them. Anyone can develop a binary called `setup.exe` and have it do pretty much whatever they want - silent install might not even be an option.

Comment: This question is not answerable. `setup.exe` couldn't get any more generic. It's a bit like asking on a car forum where the cup holders are hidden on your car without saying which car you own. Perhaps your car doesn't have cup holders. Perhaps you should talk to your car dealer or the company that built it.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the parameters, I would say you are trying to run an Inno setup. Try to add the `/SUPPRESSMSGBOXES` option:

```
setup.exe /SP- /VERYSILENT /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES
```

See [InnoSetup_Switches_ExitCodes](http://unattended.sourceforge.net/InnoSetup_Switches_ExitCodes.html) for more details